# AlarmManager and "setting alarm to turn off keyguard, seq = 10"

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, keyguard

My AlarmManager does not work properly.

The `LogCat` says that **`setting alarm to turn off keyguard, seq = 10`**.

What does this mean? How could I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code so it will be possible to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this:

1. delete AlarmManager
2. use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging for Android) to show a notification

*Before I used AlarmManager to check manually for updates...*